# TypeError: can't concat bytes to str(python3)

Tags: web-crawler

I am trying to get some news from a website, but there is a problem.

```
import urllib.request
user_agent = 'Chrome/58.0(compatible;IE 10.0; Windows 10)'
headers = {'User-Agent': user_agent}
url = 'http://www.1905.com/list-p-catid-221.html'
request=urllib.request.Request(url,headers)
response=urllib.request.urlopen(request)
first=response.read()
print(first)
f = open('WebCrawler/1905/film/index.2.txt','wb')
f.write(first)
```

The problem is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Heidy/PycharmProjects/untitled1/m2.py", line 7, in <module>
    response=urllib.request.urlopen(request)
  ....
TypeError: can't concat bytes to str
```

I just started to learn Python and crawler.If you are willing to help me, thank you very much!
I added `.decode('utf-8')` to the `response.read()`, but it's useless.
this is full traceback:

```
enter code here
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/Heidy/PycharmProjects/untitled1/m2.py", line 7, in <module>
response=urllib.request.urlopen(request)
File "C:\Users\Heidy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-
32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 223, in urlopen
return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
File "C:\Users\Heidy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-
32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 526, in open
response = self._open(req, data)
File "C:\Users\Heidy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-
32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 544, in _open
'_open', req)
File "C:\Users\Heidy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-
32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 504, in _call_chain
result = func(*args)
File "C:\Users\Heidy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-
32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1346, in http_open
return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPConnection, req)
File "C:\Users\Heidy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-
32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1318, in do_open
encode_chunked=req.has_header('Transfer-encoding'))
File "C:\Users\Heidy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-
32\lib\http\client.py", line 1239, in request
self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
File "C:\Users\Heidy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-
32\lib\http\client.py", line 1285, in _send_request
self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
File "C:\Users\Heidy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-
32\lib\http\client.py", line 1234, in endheaders
self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
File "C:\Users\Heidy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-
32\lib\http\client.py", line 1064, in _send_output
+ b'\r\n'
TypeError: can't concat bytes to str
```

Comment: Please give the *full* traceback.

Comment: Use : `request=urllib.request.Request(url, headers=headers)`

Comment: But the text I got is a messy code.???

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
request=urllib.request.Request(url,headers)
```

to

```
request=urllib.request.Request(url = url,headers = headers)
```